# Is there a bridge needed to connect Pro Mini 3.3v to HC-05 (level 3.3v)?

Tags: arduino-pro-mini, hc-05

I can't understand how to connect my arduino pro mini https://www.amazon.in/gp/product/B071ZCHW5P/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1

To my HC-05 Bluetooth module https://www.ebay.in/itm/HC05-Wireless-Bluetooth-RF-Transceiver-Module-Serial-TTL/182970488321?ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT&_trksid=p2057872.m2749.l2649

There is a guide to connect them given here : http://www.instructables.com/id/Bluetooth-Serial-Adapter-for-Pro-Mini/

I am trying to follow this guide but it is for 5V version and involves shorting the diode on the pro mini plus a divider circuit.

Here is the circuit:[image]

Apparently, there is an obvious difference in the circuit according to my components.

Please help me connect them correctly.

Thanks :)

Comment: Double check that your pro mini is a 3.3V (the comment on Amazon states it is NOT 3.3V version). If it is, and you confirm that the HC is 3V3 too, you don't need the voltage divider (just use the wires). As for the diode, you just have to check that the power arrives to the HC; if it doesn't, try getting it from another VCC pin (or short circuit the diode as suggested in the instructable). Just note that the author says that you have to connect TX with TX and RX with RX; if your solution doesn't work try swapping them

Comment: If both devices are 3,3 volt, there is no need for the 10K/15K voltage divider. The Rx pin on the HC-05 is only receiving 1.98volt as a logical 1 and thet is way to low.